# In cakephp, how can I set conditions for a model that is not associated with the one I am paginating but which is associated to one that is?

Tags: cakephp, pagination, associations, models, cakephp-1.3

I am paginating ($this->Customer->paginate()) on the 'Customer' model.

The customer model is associated to the 'Contact' model which in turn is associated to the 'ContactAddress' model.

So:

Customer hasMany Contact

Contact belongsTo ContactAddress

Now I want to paginate customers in the 'Customers->index()' using a search query let's say 'ContactAddress.city' LIKE '%New%'

How do I do this? When I do it in the conditions for paginate it says: "Unknown column 'ContactAddress.city' in 'where clause'" logically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that is very very satisfactory.

I looked through the complicated code of the pagination functionality and found, logically, that paginate sets conditions and passes these to a find function of the model (unless the model has it's own 'paginate' function).

I first tried overriding the paginate function, but this was too complicated. The solution I found in the end is to pass on joins to the paginate's options just like you would pass them when doing 'find' on a model:

```
    //Set the pagination options:   
    `$this->paginate = array(
        'limit' => 25,
        'order' => array(
        'Customer.lastname1' => 'asc'
        ),
        'joins' =>
        array(
                // OUTER JOIN because I wanted to also 
                // fetch record that do not have a 'contact'
        array(
            'table' => 'contacts',
            'alias' => 'Contact',
            'type' => 'LEFT OUTER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Customer.id = Contact.customer_id',
                'Contact.class' => 'ContactAddress'
            )
            ),
        array(
            'table' => 'contact_addresses',
            'alias' => 'ContactAddress',
            'type' => 'LEFT OUTER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Contact.index = ContactAddress.id',
            )
            ),
        ),
        // In your conditions you can now use any table that 
        // was joined as well as the original 'customer' table.
        'conditions' => $conditions,

    );

    $this->set('customers',$this->paginate('Customer'));
```

Either way I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Paginating on a condition twice removed is difficult in any case, Cake or not. You either need to do it in steps (find `ContactAddresses` and associated `Contact.customer_ids` first, then paginate on `Customer.id IN ($customer_ids)`) or you need to do it with subqueries. See the [manual on how to do subqueries properly](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1030/Complex-Find-Conditions) (it ain't pretty).

What's better depends on your coding skills, database size and complexity of the resulting query. Test both and decide what works for you.

Comment: The query itself is not very troublesome, I created the pure sql query that does what I want. The trouble is to make cake do it.

The query: |
SELECT * 
FROM customers as cust
LEFT JOIN contacts as cont
ON cust.id = cont.customer_id
LEFT JOIN contact_addresses as addr
ON cont.index = addr.id
WHERE cont.class = 'ContactAddress'
AND addr.city LIKE '%%Brus%';|

It works just fine.

Comment: there are a few behaviors like linkable that my be able to help you. with std cake you are out of luck